# Why is the static library of the three-way library I'm using so much larger than its dynamic library?

Tags: c++, dll, linker, lib, podofo

The three-way library I use is podofo:
https://github.com/podofo/podofo
for reading and modifying PDF files.

I have been using the dynamic version of the library provided by vcpkg, now I need to use the static version of the library from podofo, so I compiled a static library using the source code, but it was too big (about 130M), after that I used vcpkg to build the static library from podofo, it became even bigger (about 210M).

I know that static libraries copy in their dependencies, but the size of the dynamic versions of the libraries that podofo depends on when I add them up (about 30M) is also much smaller than podofo's static library file.

Am I doing something wrong there?

**try:**
using "vcpkg install podofo:x64-windows-static" get podofo static lib.

**expecting:**
Confirm that this is normal

If it is normal, is there any way to reduce the size of the static library.

Comment: Does `vcpkg` actually build things?  I've never used it, but I thought it was just a package manager and downloads prebuilt libs from wherever they might be hiding in the cloud.

Comment: @PaulSanders yes you compile packages from source code using `vcpkg` in many cases CMake is used but it does have support for other building tools.

Comment: I think the main reason is that vcpkg uses `/Z7` when building libraries, i.e. debugging information is embedded into .lib file.